# How to specify and locate cells using Pandas and use fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data, data-preprocessing

I am using a dataset that can be found on Kaggle website (https://www.kaggle.com/claytonmiller/lbnl-automated-fault-detection-for-buildings-data).
I am trying to **write a code that can specify based on Timestamp to look for those specific rows and apply a condition** (In the context of this dataset the time between 10:01 PM to 6:59 AM) and f**ill all the columns corresponding to those specific rows with zero**.

I have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime as dt
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('RTU.csv')

def fill_na(row):
    if dt.time(22, 1) <= pd.to_datetime(row['Timestamp']).time() <= dt.time(6, 59):
        row.fillna(0)
        
### df = df.apply(fill_na, axis=1) ###
df= df.apply(lambda row : fill_na(row), axis=1)
#### df.fillna(0, inplace=True) ###
df.head(2000)
```

However after changing the axis of the dataset it seems it can no longer work as intended.

Comment: Can you do that comparison? Shound't you make two different ones like `if dt.time(22, 1) <= pd.to_datetime(row['Timestamp']).time() <= dt.time(0,0) or dt.time(0, 0) <= pd.to_datetime(row['Timestamp']).time() <= dt.time(6,59)`? The way it is written it seems to always return False

Comment: The answer given by EBDS does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a function to do that.  Just filter the rows using a condition and then fillna.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('RTU.csv',parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
df.head()

cond = (df.Timestamp.dt.time > dt.time(22,0)) | ((df.Timestamp.dt.time < dt.time(7,0)))
df[cond] = df[cond].fillna(0,axis=1)
```

Shows that the na before 7am fill with 0

[image]